# how to set the color of dividerwidth in column header

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridcolumnheader

I've set the divider width and divider height to non-zero and then used `dataGridview1.GridColor = Color.Red` to set the color of the dividers. This doesn't affect the header though. How can I change the color of the gap between the header cells?; i.e. How can I make that gap Red also?

[image: datagrid example with white divider]

Comment: Did you see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersborderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: yup, i've played with that code without finding an answer. (interestingly, that example code omitted dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false which is needed.)

Comment: I meant the 1st note, which for me implies that is not possible without turning off EnableHeadersVisualStyles  and who would want that?? So I guess you need to ownerdraw the columnheaders..

Comment: See my update!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**  The trick is to allow your own styles to be applied in the Headers. To do this you need this line to turn off the `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` flag:

```
  dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

Without it the user settings are applied. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.enableheadersvisualstyles.aspx?ppud=4)

---

Old answer:

You can always do stuff by owner-drawing the header cells.

Here is a short example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0) return;  // only the column headers!
    // the hard work still can be done by the system:
    e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
    e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
    // now for the lines in the header..
    Rectangle r = e.CellBounds;
    using (Pen pen0 = new Pen(dataGridView1.GridColor, 1))
    {
        // first vertical grid line:
        if (e.ColumnIndex < 0) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen0, r.X, r.Y, r.X, r.Bottom);
        // right border of each cell:
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen0, r.Right - 1, r.Y, r.Right - 1, r.Bottom);
    }
    e.Handled = true;  // stop the system from any further work on the headers
}
```

[image]